# Erro ao contar valores repetido em um vetor

Tags: c, array

Estou tentando fazer uma questão que conte o numero de vezes que cada valor aparece no vetor, o que eu tentei, só conta um numero repetido, alguém poderia me ajudar com a lógica,
Exemplo de entrada 8
10
8
260
4
10
10

Saida 4 aparece 1 vez(es)
8 aparece 2 vez(es)
10 aparece 3 vez(es)
260 aparece 1 vez(es)

A saida que meu código apresenta 
4 aparece 1 vez
Meu código

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAM 100

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int vetor[TAM], num, fre[TAM] = {0};

   for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
   {
      scanf("%d", &num);
      ++fre[num];
      vetor[i] = num;
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
   {
      printf("O numero %d se repete %d\n", vetor[i], fre[i]);
   }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não está verificando se o número já existe no vetor, caso ele já exista incremente o seu contador e senão o adiciona.

```
bool bNumeroJaExiste = false;
for (int j = 0; j < TAM && !bNumeroJaExiste; j++)
{
    //    O número já existe?
    if (num == vetor[j])
    {
        ++fre[j];    //    incrementa o contador na posição do número encontrado.
        bNumeroJaExiste = true;
    }
}

if (!bNumeroJaExiste)
{
    //  Adiciona o número no vetor.
    ++fre[i];
    vetor[i] = num;
}
```

Comment: ao invés de vetor.size() deve usar TAM, ele indicou C e não C++

Comment: @prmottajr Obrigado. Não tinha reparado.